# JSP JSTL <c:if="${1 == 2}"> returning true

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've been having issues where JSTL c:if  does not seem to be working correctly.. so I tested it with the following statement...

```
<c:if="${1 == 2}">
   1 is equal to 2
</c:if>
```

And it is outputting "1 is equal to 2"...

Is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT: found the issue and it was me being silly.. the problem was I'd forgot to include the jstl core tag library in the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EL expression with the condition has to be a value of the `test` attribute.

```html
<c:if test="${1 == 2}">
   1 is equal to 2
</c:if>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL `<c:if>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html)